# Jquery Mobile: DatePicker with multiple months

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am new in jQuery mobile. Is it possible to display multiple months with vertical scroll in a date picker using Jquery mobile. I used `numberOfMonths` in jQueryUI.

I want to create the same using jQuery mobile with vertical scrolls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't whether it would work for mobile or not(But, i guess it will work); But you can use `numberOfMonths` for the same purpose with an option to show it vertically ,

> numberOfMonthsType: Number or Array
>
> Default: 1 The number of months to show at once. Multiple types
>   supported: Number: The number of months to display in a single row.
>   Array: An array defining the number of rows and columns to display.

So, you can use ,

```
numberOfMonths: [3,1]
```

To show 3 months vertically in 1 column.

#### See the [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/D4AGz/334/)